# ¿Cómo marcar registros repetidos de 2 columnas en VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macros, microsoft-office

' Marcar el aula y horario si es que se encuentra repetido para evitar empalme de materias

La siguiente Macro me busca y compara por columnas separadas y necesito comparar la fila H8 e I8 como único registro para poder marcarlos.

[image]

Sub horariosDuplicados()
Dim Fila As Long
Dim Fila2 As Long
Dim Final As Long
Dim Final2 As Long

```
Final = Range("H8").End(xlDown).Row ' Columna de horarios
Final2 = Range("I8").End(xlDown).Row ' Columna de aulas

For Fila = 1 To Final
    For Fila2 = 1 To Final2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H8:H" & Final), Range("H" & Fila2)) > 1 And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("I8:I" & Final2), Range("I" & Fila2)) > 1 Then
            Range("H" & Fila2).Font.Color = -16776961
            Range("I" & Fila2).Font.Color = -16776961
        Else
            Range("H" & Fila2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
            Range("I" & Fila2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        End If
    Next Fila2
Next Fila
```

End Sub

Comment: ¿Y qué problema tienes? ¿Qué falla en el código? ¿Qué error sale?¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Hola, disculpa tal ves no me di a entender, en la imagen publicada se muestra como compara por columnas separadas y necesito comparar la fila H8 e I8 como único registro para poder marcarlos pero en vez de eso  comparo todas las columnas entonces si tengo un dato repetido en I10 y I8  pero en H8 y H10 son distintos se me marca como repetido porque en I10 Y I8 son los mismo datos pero quiero poder diferenciar que aunque sea el mismo aula pero hora distinta no se marquen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No lo he testeado, pero deberías probar con COUNTIFS:

Tienes esto en tu código:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("H8:H" & Final), Range("H" & Fila2)) > 1 And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("I8:I" & Final2), Range("I" & Fila2)) > 1 Then...
```

Y debería ser:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("H8:H" & Final), Range("H" & Fila2),Range("I8:I" & Final2), Range("I" & Fila2)) > 1 Then...
```

Es decir, debes contar cuantas filas cumplen **ambas** condiciones a la vez. Tu código ahora las cuenta por separado, y por eso aunque estén en diferente número de fila, lo colorea.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de maravilla